# Springcloud feign client parse params in wrong way under Hoxton.SR1

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

Recently, i upgraded the cloud version from Edgware.RELEASE to Hoxton.SR1,and encounter some problems.
here comes the feign client code :

```
@FeignClient(name = "system-service)
public interface IHelloProxy{
  @RequestMapping(value = "/sysinfo/now", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void hello(@RequestParam String content);
}
```

when invoked IHelloProxy and pass the one param "content" with "https://www.oschina.net/?a=1&b=2"，the feign debug log print:

```
---> GET http://system-service/sysinfo/now?content=https:%2F%2Fwww.oschina.net%2F%3Fa=1&b=2 HTTP/1.1
```

and the receiver got two params：“content”,"b".

the expectation should be :

```
--> GET http://system-service/sysinfo/now?content=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oschina.net%2F%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2
```

and the receiver also got only one param :"content"

I think the problem is at feign client side which do the wrong query map parsing. is that anyway to solve this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the problem had solved by upgrade the cloud version to Hoxton.SR1 and Boot verion to 2.2.5.

and the issue is from open feign side, can track by for more detail

```
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/1190
```